# Cannot find namespace 'firebase' in Angular5 project

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, tsconfig

I am trying to integrate angularfire2 and firebase in my angular 5 project but it gives 'firebase' namespace error.

> **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular5-firebase",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/firebase": "^2.4.32",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.8.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

I have tried following soluntions but none of them solve my problem.

- import * as firebase from 'firebase' in app.module.ts;
- "types": ["firebase"] in tsconfig.json
- installed @types/firebase using 'npm install --save @types/firebase'

After all this I have installed firebase typings with 'typings install firebase --save' and added ' "files": ["typings/index.d.ts"] ' in tsconfig.json. It removes all error of namespace from console but when I check localhost:4200 in browser no view was rendered there. By inspecting element I can see that no view is rendered in .

[image]

> **tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ],
        "types": [
            "firebase"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue has been posted here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1387.

So you should keep on old version of `firebase` while they make a new release.

```
npm uninstall --save firebase
npm install --save firebase@4.8.0
```